# Retrieve numeric bit value from EnumSet

Tags: java

I am using an EnumSet to do bitwise permission operations, as suggested in Effective Java, Item 32. This is nice and concise, but I need I to extract the numeric bit value, to interface with an older system that expects a numeric value. Using a BitSet this is straightforward using the enums ordinal value, but EnumSet doesn't seem to have it built in. Do I just have to write it myself?

```
public enum Permissions {
      EDIT,     // 1
      SAVE,     // 2
      DELETE,   // 4
      WHATEVER  // 8
};

EnumSet<Flags> flags = EnumSet.of(EDIT, DELETE);
// long numericVal = flags.getLong(); // should be 5, but doesn't exist
```

Comment: Why not add that value as an instance field to your enum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could first add a method to the enumeration that returns its numeric value:

```
public enum Permissions
{
  EDIT,     // 1
  SAVE,     // 2
  DELETE,   // 4
  WHATEVER; // 8

  public long getNumericValue()
  {
     return (1L << ordinal());
  }

};
```

After that, loop over the entries within the set, summing the values.

```
public long getLong(EnumSet<Permissions> flags)
{
  long result;
  result = 0;
  for (Permissions element: flags)
    result += element.getNumericValue();
  return (result);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought maybe it already had the functionality built-in, given this is exactly the kind of use-case EnumSet could be use for, but it looks like it doesn't.